# Handling token identifier within a capturing group

Tags: java, regex

I've been trying to match the following text:

```json
{1:A01ABCDEFGHIJKL1234567890}{2:01234567890123ABCDEFGHIJKL12345678901234567890A}{3:{108:ABCDEFGHIJK0123}}{4:
:20:ABCDEFGHIJK/01234
:25:00000000000000000000
:28C:00001/00001
:60F:C230316EUR0,00
:62F:C230317EUR0,00
:64:C230317EUR0,00
:65:C230318EUR0,00
:65:C230319EUR0,00
:65:C230320EUR0,00
:65:C230321EUR0,00
:65:C230322EUR0,00
-}
```

using the following expression:

```
(?<=\{)([^}]+)(?=\})
```

The matching fails when the bracket is part of the matching group. For example, the group that starts with record identifier 3: is matched only partially in that the closing bracket in the group is unmatched. While I understand that this is what the expression is constructed to do, what would be an ideal way to capture also the closing bracket? In other words, match everything between two brackets that starts with a record identifier such as 1:, 2:, 3:, etc but do not apply it recursively that the nested text also don't get matched. Please advise.

[image]

Here's the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cKsRlR/1).

Comment: If there is only one level of "nesting" then maybe `(?<=\{)\d+:(?:\{[^{}]*}|[^{}]+)(?=\})`  https://regex101.com/r/xIgMPg/1

Comment: For a more general answer you may need to have a small parser instead of regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java regex does not support recursion. If there can only be 1 level of nesting, you could use an alternation:

```
(?<=\{)\d+:(?:\{\d+:[^{}]*}|[^{}]+)(?=\})
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\{)` Positive lookbehind, assert `{` to the left
- `\d+:` Match 1+ digits followed by `:`
- `(?:` Non capture group for the 2 alternatives

  - `\{\d+:[^{}]*}` Match `{` 1+ digits and `:`, and then till`}`
  - `|` Or
  - `[^{}]+` Match 1+ chars other than `{` or `}`
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `(?=\})` Positive lookahead, assert `}` to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d85LiH/1).

In Java with the double escaped backslashes:

```
String regex = "(?<=\\{)\\d+:(?:\\{\\d+:[^\\{\\}]*\\}|[^\\{\\}]+)(?=\\})";
```

Note that for a match only, you can omit the capture group.